# WatchOS application is NOT removed after removing main iOS app

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I'm developing an iOS app with WatchKit app. When I build the main app with Xcode it installs on my iPhone and the WatchKit app installs on my Watch too. But when I remove the main app from my iPhone the WatchKit app isn't removed from my Watch and works fine.

I use iOS 12.0.1 and WatchOS 5.0.1. My iOS app's deployment target is 10.0 and WatchOS app's deployment target is 4.0.

I have tried to install my app via TestFlight and behaviour isn't changed. So I'm not sure if it is only "developers" bug. Or it isn't a bug at all?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting watch and phone, then install and uninstall iPhone app again?  The watch install process has been a little flaky for a long time, but seems to have improved a lot in the last year or so.  Also, you'll usually find things behave better if the watch is on a charger while doing development.  What model watch is it?  Series 3 and 4 behave better as well, seems to be because of the faster processors.

Comment: @Cobra, thanks for your reply! Yes, I tried everything from the list and nothing helps. I have watch series 3. Trying to find something in docs. Without luck for now.

Comment: It does remove from the watch if you go to the iPhone Watch app and remove just your watch app that way?  I haven't tried removing an iPhone app with a watch app in a while, I'll have to see.

Comment: @Cobra, after few reboots the app disappears. It is really strange behaviour. I didn't get which reboot, iPhone, Watch or both normalise everything.
My researches on API and docs wasn't successful. I set breakpoints on actions and all delegate methods. Seems like iOS doesn't notify WatchOS about main app got deleted. `WCSession.isReachable` is `true`. The only thing is sending messages returns timeout error after around 4-5 minutes.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hang long do you wait after you remove the iPhone app?  There were times in the past were it could take quite a while for install/uninstall on the watch to finish.  Or it didn't seem to succeed at all.  I thought that was mostly resolved (actually had a bug/radar in against that back in watchOS 2, IIRC.)  If it impacts your testing, I would just remove the watch app first in the iPhone watch app, so you know it's gone.